# symfony assetic get 500 error for js file

Tags: symfony, assetic

This just started on production.  The file javascript file is there but gives a 500 error, with no other information.

> 500 Internal\u0020Server\u0020Error

running

```sh
bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

shows the compiled file.

config part looks like this:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    bundles:        [appBundle]
    filters:
        uglifyjs2:
            # the path to the uglifyjs executable
            bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
        uglifycss:
            bin: /usr/bin/uglifycss
        #cssrewrite:
           # apply_to: "\.css$"
   # java: /usr/bin/java
```

template reference -

```
<!-- include javascripts --->
{% javascripts '@appBundle/Resources/public/js/*' filter='uglifyjs2' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

htaccess file -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^livemusic/web/app.php - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ livemusic/web/app.php [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^\robots.txt [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: in your browser navigator , can you check the path which looking for the load the file ?

Comment: it's https://website/js/1504570.js

Comment: Do you see any errors/warnings in your log files under `var/log(s)`? Can you show your web server config (apache - maybe with a .htaccess file in `web/` -, nginx)? More specifically are file requests routed through your front controller (app.php/app_dev.php) or are they handled directly?

Comment: @dbrumann only errors are GET 500 error for the js file.  I've added the .htaccess in the question, if that's what you mean.  I think file request must be routed through app.php though not certain how to check this.  The file was working though I did do a load of dumping assets and trying dump with --symlink to get css to work, with no luck, and this seems to have messed up the js.  this was another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439064/symfony-css-images-sub-folder-files-not-viewable-on-production